# List<T> paging asp.net

Tags: entity-framework, list, gridview, data-paging

Using a three-tier architecture, I have a list of objects

```
 List<object> careerList = new List<object>();
            ModuleDTO module = new ModuleDTO();
            careerList = module.getDegreeCodeByQualification(qualificationCode);
```

which I then add to a gridview like so:

```
 gridViewMaster.DataSource = careerList;
            gridViewMaster.DataBind();
```

What I'd like to do is then enable paging on the gridview. My gridview so far is:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gridViewMaster" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None"
        BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2" DataKeyNames="Grouping" 
        ForeColor="Black"
            onrowdatabound="gridViewMaster_RowDataBound" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"  
AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" OnPageIndexChanging="gridView_PageIndexChanging" 
                AllowPaging="True" >
```

Is it possible to do enable paging on a list's without having to change that list to a Datatable or Dataview? If there is a way, this would help a lot.

So far my events are as follows:

```
protected void gridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gridViewMaster.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        List<object> careerList = new List<object>();
            ModuleDTO module = new ModuleDTO();
            careerList = module.getDegreeCodeByQualification(qualificationCode);
            ModalProgress.Show();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            JobPanel.Visible = true;
            gridViewMaster.DataSource = careerList.Distinct();
            gridViewMaster.DataBind();
    }
```

Someone PLEASE HELP ME!!! Thank you

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/jaycentdrysdale/archive/2009/07/13/list-lt-t-gt-paging-via-linq-to-objects.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have your code working, with a GridView paging from a List databinding.  Message me if you have any more issues after trying the following checks:

1. Make sure this code returns a list of items with a property named "Grouping" because you have it listed as a DataKeyName in your GridView like so:

   careerList = module.getDegreeCodeByQualification(qualificationCode);
2. My GridView code looks like this:

   ```
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" GridLines="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2" DataKeyNames="Grouping" 
       ForeColor="Black" AllowPaging="True" 
       onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" AutoGenerateColumns="true" PageSize="2">
   </asp:GridView>
   ```

... note the new "PageSize" and "AutoGenerateColumns" attributes that I added.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! I'm no longer getting any compiler errors. My only problem is now, when I change my index, it changes the actual index, but it doesn't update my gridview. I think it's because I'm reloading the data from scratch and not from the next index. What would you suggest I do? Again, BIG thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! Feel like an idiot, but I was binding to the wrong gridview, but your answer helped perfectly! Thank you SO SO much.

Here is what I did, for anyone else with the same problem:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridQualifications" runat="server"
    CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"  
AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridQualifications_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    AllowPaging="True" PageSize="2" OnPageIndexChanging="gridView_PageIndexChanging">
 <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />

protected void gridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridQualifications.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindData();
    }
```

Where I bound my data the same way anyone should, using a List as my datasource.

Many thanks for all the stress you have just relieved :D :D

Comment: Nice :).  I find that stepping through the code patiently using Visual Studio debugging tools thoroughly will give you the answers 9 times out of 10.